# Turns of closed path $\lambda$ around origin is related to area of paralelogram $\lambda(t), \lambda'(t)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry

> Given the closed path $\lambda:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R^2}-\{0\}$, $C^1$,
>   call $A(t)$ the 'oriented area' of the paralelogram determined by the
>   vectors $\lambda(t)$ and $\lambda'(t)$ for each $t\in [a,b]$. Show
>   that the number of turns that $\lambda$ does arount he origin is:
>
> $$n(\lambda, 0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_a^b \frac{A(t)}{|\lambda(t)|^2}\
>  dt$$

- The oriented area of a paralelogram such that its sides are given by vectros $v,w\in \mathbb{R^2}$, in this order, is positive when the rotation is from $v\to w$ by the least anti-clockwise angle, negative otherwise, and $0$ is the vectors are linearly dependent

As I understood, for each $t$, we have one $\lambda(t)$ and $\lambda'(t)$. We must consider the paralelogram formed by these $2$ vectors for each $t$ and call $A(t)$ its area in the point $t$. But I honestly can't see a relation from this to turns around the origin.

Comment: In complex analysis it is called the winding number  $\displaystyle n(\gamma,0) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z} = \int_a^b \frac{\gamma'(t) dt}{\gamma(t)} = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \log \gamma(t) |_a^b$

Comment: Thanks for the "acceptance"!  Now I'm going to try your other problem.  I may have a few questions . . .

Comment: By the way, I added the "differential geometry" tag to your post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to realize that, if we express $\lambda(t)$ in polar coordinates $(r(t), \theta(t))$, then

$\theta'(t) = \dfrac{d\theta}{dt} = \dfrac{A(t)}{\vert \lambda(t) \vert^2}. \tag 1$

We now demonstrate this amazing fact.  In so doing, it will be convenient to introduce the standard *cylidnrical coordinate system* $(r, \theta, z)$ on $\Bbb R^3$, and to consider the planar polars $(r, \theta)$ to be embedded in the cylidnrical system in the conventional manner.

The vector $\lambda(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, when expressed in polar coordinates, is

$\lambda(t) = (r(t) \cos \theta(t), r(t) \sin \theta(t)) = r(t)(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t)); \tag 2$

thus, in the cylindrical system, we have

$\lambda(t) = (r(t) \cos \theta(t), r(t) \sin \theta(t), 0) = r(t)(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0); \tag 3$

in these terms,

$\vert \lambda(t) \vert = \sqrt{r^2(t) \sin^2 \theta(t) + r^2(t) \cos^2 \theta(t)} = r(t); \tag 4$

also, from (3),

$\lambda'(t) = r'(t)(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) + r(t) (\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0)'$
$= r'(t)(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) + r(t)\theta'(t)(-\sin \theta(t), \cos \theta(t), 0). \tag 5$

Now the signed area $A(t)$ of the parallelogram whose sides are $\lambda(t)$ and $\lambda'(t)$ is

$A(t) = (\lambda(t) \times \lambda'(t)) \cdot \mathbf k, \tag 6$

where "$\times$" is the ordinary vector cross product in $\Bbb R^3$, and $\mathbf k$ is the usual unit normal vector to the $x$-$y$ plane, which is spanned by the usual unit vectors $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$; see [this widipedia article on the cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).  We compute $(\lambda(t) \times \lambda'(t))\cdot \mathbf k$ based upon (2) and (5):

$\lambda(t) \times \lambda'(t)$
$= r(t)(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) \times (r'(t)(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) + r(t)\theta'(t)(-\sin \theta(t), \cos \theta(t), 0))$
$= r(t)r'(t)((\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) \times (\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0))$
$+ r^2(t) \theta'(t)((\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) \times (-\sin \theta(t), \cos \theta(t), 0)); \tag 7$

now

$(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) \times (\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) = 0, \tag 8$

and

$(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t), 0) \times (-\sin \theta(t), \cos \theta(t), 0) = \mathbf k; \tag 9$

bringing (8) and (9) into (7) yields

$\lambda(t) \times \lambda'(t) = r^2(t)\theta'(t) \mathbf k; \tag{10}$

thus,

$A(t) = (\lambda(t) \times \lambda'(t)) \cdot \mathbf k = r^2(t)\theta'(t) \mathbf k \cdot \mathbf k = r^2(t) \theta'(t), \tag{11}$

or, *via* (4),

$A(t) = \vert \lambda(t) \vert^2 \theta'(t), \tag{12}$

whence

$\theta'(t) = \dfrac{A(t)}{\vert \lambda(t) \vert^2}, \tag{13}$

as was claimed.

With formula (13) in hand it is easy to dispense with the present question. Since $\lambda(t)$ is a closed path, we must have

$\lambda(a) = \lambda(b) \tag{14}$

or, in the polar system,

$(r(a)\cos \theta(a), r(a) \sin \theta(a)) = (r(b)\cos \theta(b), r(b) \sin \theta(b)), \tag{15}$

whence

$r(a) = r(b), \tag{16}$

$\cos \theta(a) = \cos \theta(b), \tag{17}$

$\sin \theta(a) = \sin \theta(b); \tag{18}$

the only way (17)-(18) can simultaneously bind is if

$\theta(b) = \theta(a) + 2\pi n \tag {19}$

for some $n \in \Bbb Z$ is clearly the number of times $\lambda(t)$ encircles the origin 'twixt $t = a$ and $t = b$; therefore we may write

$n(\lambda, 0) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}(\theta(b) - \theta(a)) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle \int_a^b \theta'(s)ds = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^b \dfrac{A(s)}{\vert \lambda(s) \vert^2} ds, \tag{20}$

as was to be shown.

Comment: You could show directly that $\frac{A(t)}{|\lambda(t)|^2}\
 dt = \Im(\frac{1}{\lambda(t)}d(\lambda(t)))$ which integrates to $\Im(\log(x))$

Comment: @reuns:  Yes, but I chose to execute a real-variable approach.  Cheers!

Comment: This is a real-variable approach !

Comment: @reuns:  I have given your suggestion some thought, it seems to be potentially elegant; why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old reply, but I've been thinking about this exercise and, unless I missed something, there's a much simpler way to solve it. I believe I'm reading the same book OP is/was reading. In there, the number of turns around the origin is defined as
$$n(\lambda; 0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\lambda} \delta \theta,\text{ where }\delta \theta = -\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^{2}}dy.$$
Now, since $\lambda$ is a $C^{1}$ path and $\delta \theta$ is a continuous $1$-form in $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$, we have the following:
$$\int_{\lambda} \delta \theta = \int_{a}^{b} \delta \theta(\lambda(t)) \cdot\lambda'(t) dt = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{-\lambda_{2}(t)\lambda_{1}'(t) + \lambda_{1}(t) \lambda_2'(t)}{|\lambda(t)|^{2}}dt.$$
Note that the expression in the numerator is the determinant of the matrix $\Lambda(t)$, where
$$\Lambda(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1(t) & \lambda_1'(t) \\ \lambda_2(t) & \lambda_2'(t) \end{bmatrix},$$
which is exactly the signed area determined by $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$.