# $\mu(t) = (x(t)\cos \alpha - y(t)\sin \alpha, x(t)\sin \alpha+y(t)\cos \alpha)$, paths $\lambda$ and $u$ give same ammount of turns

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, curves

> Let $\lambda:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R^2}-\{0\}$ be a $C^1$ sectionally closed
>   path and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ a constant. Define
>   $\mu:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R^2}-\{0\}$ by doing $\mu(t) = e^{i \alpha}\cdot
>  \lambda(t) = (x(t)\cos \alpha - y(t)\sin \alpha, x(t)\sin
>  \alpha+y(t)\cos \alpha)$, where $\lambda(t) = (x(t), y(t))$. Prove that the paths
>   $\lambda$ and $u$ give the same number of turns around the origin.

I noted that $|\mu| = |e^{i\alpha}||\lambda(t)| = |\lambda(t)|$. I think it has to do with integration. I also had this exercise: [Turns of closed path $\lambda$ around origin is related to area of paralelogram $\lambda(t), \lambda'(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404188/turns-of-closed-path-lambda-around-origin-is-related-to-area-of-paralelogram) but this question comes before this exercise, so I must not use the formula present there.

However, I think it has to do with integration, because I'm studying Stieltjes integration, homotopic curves and so. How can I connect these results to solve this exercise?

Comment: HInt:$$\begin{cases}X=x(t)\cos \alpha - y(t)\sin \alpha\\Y=x(t)\sin \alpha+y(t)\cos \alpha\end{cases}\\X^2+Y^2=(x(t)\sin \alpha+y(t)\cos \alpha)^2+(x(t)\sin \alpha+y(t)\cos \alpha)^2\\=x^2(t)(\cos^2 \alpha+\sin^2 \alpha)+y^2(t)(\cos^2 \alpha+\sin^2 \alpha)+2x(t)y(t)\cos \alpha.\sin \alpha-2x(t)y(t)\cos \alpha.\sin \alpha\\=x(t)^2+y^2(t)$$

Comment: But that's what I noted in the question. What do i do now?

Comment: What is a "sectionally closed path"?